# Jybot/Pybot issue with Robotframework on Mac

Tags: python, bash, macos, robotframework

I'm trying to run the robotframework on Pycharm on Mac EI captain. I have installed Pycharm, Robotframework for Python and jython. I can see the pybot and jybot files on Python and Jython directories respectively. When I run the command `pybot --version` and `jybot --version` I get an error saying `"-bash: pybot command not found"`

Here is my environment variables:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home

export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/*.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/*.jar

export PATH=${PATH}/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:/Users/el/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages:/Users/el/Library/Python/2.7:/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.0/libexec/bin
```

I am using Jython 2.7.0 and Python 2.7.1. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: check if those locations are listed under PATH , if not just do export PATH=<PATH_TO_INSTALLED_PYTHON>:$PATH and try again

Comment: @Sanju - I have updated my environment variable above. I looks good to me. In terminal, I am able to get the Jython version but not for the Pybot/Jybot. So, I'm not getting this issue on EI Capitan but I'm now facing it on Mac Sierra.